# How can I add up all the numbers in a range that is set by variables?

Tags: python, sum

I have to use the sum function but it isn't working for me. Here is my code so far:

```
def main():

    print('This program will total all the numbers in a range.')


    num1 = (int(input('Enter a number.')))
    num2 = (int(input('Enter another number (smaller than the first one).')))

    for i in range(num1 - num2 + 1):

        print(i + num2)
    print(sum(range(num1, num2 + 1)))

main()
```

The sum is always wrong by a lot, and I cant figure out have to make it right.

Comment: If num1 is larger than num2, then you should do `range(num2, num1+1)`.

Comment: Provide some example output, code as written seems to work fine as long as the first number is less than the second number

Comment: As num1 is larger than num2 in the last line it is not creating the list of numbers you are expecting and hence sum will always be zero. As suggested by @Kota Mori you need to interchange the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
def main():
    print("\nThis program will total all the numbers in a range.")

    num_1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    num_2 = int(input("Enter another number: "))
    something = [num_1, num_2]

    max_num = max(something)
    min_num = min(something)
    new_list = list(range(min_num, max_num+1))

    current_sum = min_num
    for i in new_list[1:]:
        print(f"{current_sum} + {i} = ", end='')
        current_sum += i
        print(f"{current_sum}")

    print(f"\nSum of all numbers in range: {current_sum}")

while True:
    main()
```

If you find the `min` and `max` of the two `input`'s you can eliminate the need for the user to enter them in proper order.

For the general procedure, you can just `+=` a running sum for each number in the `range` designated by the user.

Alternatively you could also use this code, in place of using `max` & `min`:

```
    """Replacing min/max with sorted

    max_num = max(something)
    min_num = min(something)
    new_list = list(range(min_num, max_num+1))

    current_sum = min_num
    """

    something = sorted(something)
    new_list = list(range(something[0], something[1]+1))

    current_sum = new_list[0]
```

**Output**

> ```
> This program will total all the numbers in a range.
> Enter a number: 5
> Enter another number: -5
> -5 + -4 = -9
> -9 + -3 = -12
> -12 + -2 = -14
> -14 + -1 = -15
> -15 + 0 = -15
> -15 + 1 = -14
> -14 + 2 = -12
> -12 + 3 = -9
> -9 + 4 = -5
> -5 + 5 = 0
>
> Sum of all numbers in range: 0
> ```

**Fun**

Ran 0 to 1000000 :)

> ```
> 499995500010 + 999996 = 499996500006
> 499996500006 + 999997 = 499997500003
> 499997500003 + 999998 = 499998500001
> 499998500001 + 999999 = 499999500000
> 499999500000 + 1000000 = 500000500000
>
> Sum of all numbers in range: 500000500000
> ```

**Updates**

Spruced up the `print` statements in the loop to give it that running total look, that it appears you had originally sought out.

Changed `current_sum` from `0` to `min_num` and then started loop at `new_list[1:]`. This doesn't effect the sum but this eliminates a `print` statement that showed `0 + x = x`.

Added using `sorted` method as alternative to using `max` & `min`